# what is the Definition of acc in haskell?

Tags: haskell

I've just started to study haskell and i saw this function as a sample solution to a question
in this question you should write a function using foldl to reverse a given list.

```
rev :: [Int]-> [Int]
rev = foldl (\acc x -> x: acc) []
```

i know what this function is doing and i know that it takes an anonymous function as Argument. what i would like to know is a simple definition of  acc (accumulator)in haskell and yes i googled that before! but i still can not understand the it's definition in different functions.
is there any rule for using it as an Argument in functions? does it come only in anonymous functions?
couldn't we just write it like  this \x -> x: xs ?

Comment: `acc` is just variable name, you can rename it.

Comment: you couldn't write it as `\x -> x:xs` because that would have the wrong number of arguments

'acc' is a popular argument name in folds just because it implies what the argument refers to - namely, the result of the previous iteration of the function, which has historically often been called an accumulator

Comment: `(\acc x -> x : acc)` == `(\a x -> x : a)` == `(\a b -> b : a)` == `(\b a -> a : b)`. but it's better to hint at the variables' types (list or not a list) with the plural "s",  so, `(\as b -> b : as)` == `(\xs x -> x : xs)` etc..

Answer (score 4):

'acc' has no definition beyond its type, as described by the type signature of foldl (specialised to lists):

```
foldl :: (b -> a -> b) -> b -> [a] -> b
```

the `(b -> a -> b)` describes the anonymous function in question

note how the first argument, which is commonly called 'acc' by convention (but could just as easily be called anything else), shares a type with the result of the function - this is due to how the function is used

for example:

```
foldl (\acc x -> x : acc) [] [1,2,3,4]
= foldl (\acc x -> x : acc) (1 : []) [2,3,4]
= foldl (\acc x -> x : acc) (2 : (1 : [])) [3,4]
= foldl (\acc x -> x : acc) (3 : (2 : (1 : []))) [4]
= foldl (\acc x -> x : acc) (4 : (3 : (2 : (1 : [])))) []
= 4 : (3 : (2 : (1 : [])))
= [4,3,2,1]
```

as you can see, each step uses the result of the previous step as the first argument - this result is called an "accumulator" for historical reasons, and so calling the argument "acc" suggests what it refers to

this is primarily useful since foldl and foldr swap around the input arguments, so it can be easy to mix up which argument is which when defining folds

naming the accumulator argument 'acc' means you only need to remember which one is which when naming the arguments at the start, and so makes it significantly easier to define more complicated folds, and also makes code more legible in general

Comment: One might also see `i` or `init` as that binding represents the initial state provided to a fold on each iteration.

Answer (score 3):

`acc` is just a variable name, it is here the first parameter in the lambda expression indeed:

```
rev :: [Int] -> [Int]
rev = foldl (\acc x -> x: acc) []
--             ^ first parameter
```

but you could for example use `xs` with:

```
rev :: [Int] -> [Int]
rev = foldl (\xs x -> x: xs) []
```

The variable was named `acc` because the first parameter of the fold function in [**`foldl :: Foldable f => (b -> a -> b) -> b -> f a -> b`**](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.16.1.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:foldl) is the "*accumulator*". But you do not need to name it `acc`, nor do we have to work with a lambda expression as folding function. `\acc x -> x : acc` can be replaced with `flip (:)`, so you can rewrite `rev` to:

```
rev :: [a] -> [a]
rev = foldl (flip (:)) []
```

Comment: a note about `foldl (flip (:)) []`: if you understand what `(:)` and `foldl` mean already, you can see at a glance that this is saying "starting from an empty list, run through the input list backwards, and append each element backwards to that empty list", and can infer the meaning of "reverse the input list" - a similar function would be `foldr (:) []`, which just rebuilds the original list again (if applied to another Foldable datatype, it turns it into a list, and is called `toList`)